# Porting GCC 9.3.0 or 10.3.0 in RISCV with binutils version 2.30

Tags: linux, gcc, riscv

**Commands :**

../binutils-2.30/configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/x_bin_install --with-sysroot=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/sysroot --with-arch=rv64imac --with-abi=lp64

../binutils-2.30/configure --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/h_bin_install --with-sysroot=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/sysroot --with-arch=rv64imac --with-abi=lp64

../gcc-9.3.0/configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/x_gcc_install --with-sysroot=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/sysroot --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch=rv64imac --with-abi=lp64

../gcc-9.3.0/configure --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/h_gcc_install --with-sysroot=/porting-gcc-9.3.0/sysroot --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch=rv64imac --with-abi=lp64

**gcc hello.c -o test**

/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: **unrecognised emulation mode: elf64lriscv_lp64**

Supported emulations: elf64lriscv elf32lriscv

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: is the `--with-abi=lp64` needed? It doesn't appear to have an effect on the binutils build, which only supports `elf64lriscv elf32lriscv`.

Comment: Thanks @Petesh What should i change?

Comment: Hint : https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain → `$ git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.